# *|MC:DATE|* tag not working

Tags: mailchimp, mailing

I'm trying to print out the date inside the newsletter I will be sending daily, according to the list of Merge tags from MailChimp I should be using `*|MC:DATE|*` to display it but that is not working.

A couple of things I already tried:
1.- Creating a new merge tag in the list settings.
2.- Printing it outside all the code, only inside the body tag

The [troubleshooting guide](https://kb.mailchimp.com/merge-tags/troubleshooting-merge-tags) says nothing about the tags simply not working, what else could I try?

Edit: This is the tag I am using `*|MC:DATE|*`
This is a screenshot of the account date settings: [screenshot of settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BMH3Y.png)

Comment: You're using the tag in the body of the email?

Comment: @LightBender yes I am.

Comment: Could you add a code sample containing the merge tag that doesn't work for you?

Comment: It says it bases the date on your account defaults, can you confirm they are set correctly?

Comment: @JoelH. I'm trying to use it as a standalone without any code inside the body tag and it is not working

Comment: @LightBender I posted a screenshot of my date settings

Comment: Do other merge tags work for you?

Comment: @JoelH.Yeas, *|CURRENT_YEAR|* was working.